# Is there a technical limitation that prevents a pure javascript client (running in the browser) from using the Feedly Cloud API?

Tags: javascript, oauth, client-side, feedly

I'd like to use the Feedly Cloud API, but I'm hoping to build my app in a pure client-side fashion. From what I can see on the Feedly developer docs, there is no client-side JavaScript library available to access the API. This seems strange to me, since the API is RESTful and serializes to JSON.

**Why is there no pure JavaScript client for the Feedly Cloud API that runs inside the browser?**

Is there some kind of technical limitation caused by OAuth or the design of the Feedly API that prevents a client from connecting strictly through the end user's browser?

If it is simply an issue of "nobody has built one yet", that's fine. I just want to make sure that I'm not doing something crazy before I write a JS client.

Comment: Using a developer key, I get this response to any HTTP requests to their cloud./sandbox. apis: 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load \n http://sandbox.feedly.com/v3/categories. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.` Does this mean they aren't allowing web-based requests in general?

Comment: I've dug into this a bit further and it seems that they have a focus on mobile and desktop native apps, rather than browsers. In this light they have chosen not to provide CORS or other approaches to get around XHR security issues, meaning that a web client (like us) has to proxy all requests through his own server-side proxy, which is what we've resorted to. It sucks, but it works.